# Node.js HEROKU app doesn't update after pushing

Tags: node.js, git, github, heroku, deployment

So I a deployed a Node.js website to Heroku earlier (through Github) and today I made a few changes. I did the same `git add .` `git commit -m 'changes'` `git push` commands but the website on Heroku hasn't changed. Automatic deploys are ON. The code on my Github changed and is correct.

I also used `git push heroku master` and `heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false` , it doesn't update the code. Website still the same, like at first deploy.

Also did **purge cache**.
`heroku releases` checks out. And I checked the file with `heroku bash` on the Heroku servers, the file is also updated there. Still, I can't see the changes on the website. Tried different browsers, phones, incognito... And I only use master branch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

FIXED IT:

`npm run build` in the **client** folder. Even though I did it already before my first deploy, have to do it again after the changes. Then you can push, commit, deploy, whatever...